# How I can see all my created LInks in "developers.facebook.com"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I made some links for my apps with this api https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

I want to change some of them how i can manage my links made with Developer Facebook

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through the API, [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api) about this shows how:

> You add configuration data to an existing App Link object for a content targeted to Android like this:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/643402985734254 \
-F access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F android=' [
    {
      "url" : "sharesample://story/1234",
      "package" : "com.facebook.samples.sharesample",
      "app_name" : "ShareSample",
    },
  ]'
```

> The example shows you modifying an existing App Link object represented by the Graph API path /643402985734254 to add the Android-specific information.